# GCHandle error in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Maybe, someone could help me .. The following code to pass a 2D string array from C# to C++ works fine up to GCHandle where it gives an error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The Object does not consist any primitive information.
Actually, it worked perfectly with double 2D.

```
public static extern void DDentry
(
[In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.BStr)] string[,] arrayReadDat, int iDim1, int iDim2
);

    private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application appExcelREAD = new Excel.Application();
        appExcelREAD.Visible = true;

        string workbookPath = "C:\\Users\\Redstone\\Desktop\\eva_excel_input.xlsx";     // input file

        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook1 = appExcelREAD.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
        0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
        true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet1 = appExcelREAD.Worksheets["Tabelle1"];

        int lastRow = excelWorksheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int lastCol = excelWorksheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

        string[,] arrayReadDat = new string[lastRow+1, lastCol+1];

        for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= lastCol; j++)
            {
                arrayReadDat[i, j] = excelWorksheet1.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
            }
        }

        excelWorkbook1.Close();
        appExcelREAD.Quit();

        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(arrayReadDat, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr pArrayData = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();

        DDentry(arrayReadDat, lastRow+1, lastCol+1);

        gch.Free();
```

Comment: Well a `System.Double` is a [primitive type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.isprimitive%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and a `System.String` is not, which is what the ArgumentException and [the respective documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a95009h1(v=vs.110).aspx) says. What exactly is your question?

Comment: It is just telling you that what you are trying to do can never work, the array will be pinned but the strings won't be.  You are helping too much, just stop using GCHandle.  The next problem you need to solve is that the native code has no idea how to index that array, it knows beans about the rank of the array.  First write native code that can also be called from native code, only then try to pinvoke it.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to put in [DllImport("C:\\Users\\Redstone\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\Win32Project2\\Debug\\Win32Project2.dll",
           EntryPoint = "DDentry",
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]the same code work perfectly for 2D double arrays.

Comment: Hans: Definitely, I am not that kind of expert. How could I pass the 2D string array from C# to C++ ? As mentioned it worked for integer as well as double. How could I modify it for strings ? Many thanks.

Comment: Christian: the question is simply to pass the 2D string array arrayReadDat[i,j] from C# to C++ through DDentry(ArrayReadDat, lastRow+1, lastCol+1) .. Many thanks.